# How to remove this overlay on statusbar in emulator Flutter on Android?

Tags: android, flutter

This is the Android emulator I am using (in Android Studio). I don't know if this is going to be shown when released as well, but I want to remove this grey looking overlay. Is this by default shown because it's in debug mode or is there a way I can get rid of it?

[image]

This is what I have. If I make it light, only the text color becomes light, but I want the whole overlay to be white instead of gray(ish).

```
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change status bar color before run the app:

```dart
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.blue,
    ),
  );
  // Here you can run your app
}
```

Comment: This does not fix it. Please see edited post with code. " No named parameter with the name 'statusBarColor'."

Comment: Interesting. And do you know if this can be fully removed? As in, there is a padding created that I can't seem to remove it (even if I make it white). Is there a way?

Comment: This is status bar and it can be on real device. You can play with `SafeArea` widget, but if you doesn't care about status bar, your UI can overlay system interface.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I can't get rid of the safe area?

Comment: What reason for removing this "overlay"?

Comment: To make sure I don't need padding to put the text below that area.

Comment: What device emulator are you using?

Comment: Pixel 4, if I am correct.

Comment: This overlay can only exists on Pixel 4, and this is can be device specific stuff.